# Trying to get count of <option> as it is filtered down in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a `<select>` where the `<option>` is dynamically generated. Furthermore there is an `<input>` and as the user types it matches the characters filtering down the number of `<option>`. So if the `<input>` is blank it returns the full list and there will be a message that says `116 Results Found`. As they type "head" it will update to `8 Results Found`. Pretty common thing.

I can't figure out how to get the count. I am trying to do something in the `_.map` that counts `i++` and then `this.setState({ count: i })`; however, this basically bricks the browser as it gets stuck in an infinite loop (well, it generates thousands of the same error before I force close it because the browser is locked while it is computing).

The other idea is to count the number of `<option>` elements, but I can't figure out how to implement that.

Any suggestions?

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class BasicQuery extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            term: '',
            count: ''
        };
    }

    onInputChange(term) {
        this.setState({ term });
    }

    renderOptionsSelect(term) {
        var filterTerm = this.state.term.toLowerCase();
        var i = 0;
        return _.map(this.props.pos_list, p => {
            if (p.pos_code.toLowerCase().match(filterTerm)) {
                i++;
                return (<option key={p.pos_code} value={p.pos_code}>{p.pos_code}</option>);                        
            }
            this.setState({ count: i }); 
        });
    }

    // render the main element of the container
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='panel panel-default'>
                <div className='panel-heading'>
                    <h4><strong>Basic Query</strong></h4>
                </div>

                <div className='panel-body'>
                    <input 
                        className='form-control' 
                        placeholder='Enter Keyword or Position Code' 
                        value={this.state.term}
                        onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
                    />
                    <hr />
                    <h4>Position:</h4>
                    <select className='form-control'>
                        <option></option>
                        {this.renderOptionsSelect()}
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <h4>Data Cut:</h4>
                    <select className='form-control' disabled={true} />

                </div>
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}

// map the state in the Redux store to props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        results: state.results.results,
        pos_list: state.results.pos_list
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, null)(BasicQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
  onInputChange(term) {
    const filterTerm = term.toLowerCase();
    const filteredItems = this.props.pos_list.filter( p =>
      p.pos_code.toLowerCase().match(filterTerm)
    )
    this.setState({
      term,
      filteredItems,
      count: filteredItems.length
    });
  }
```

Then in render:

```
this.state.filteredItems.map( p =>
  <option key={p.pos_code} value={p.pos_code}>{p.pos_code}</option>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your render method you can first call `renderOptionsSelect` and then get the number of generated options (since it is an array) and display it. And then I would also filter your array of options like this:

```
renderOptionsSelect(term) {
    var filterTerm = this.state.term.toLowerCase();

    return this.props.pos_list
      .filter(p => p.pos_code.toLowerCase().match(filterTerm))
      .map(p => (<option key={p.pos_code} value={p.pos_code}>{p.pos_code}</option>));
}

render() {
    const options = this.renderOptionsSelect();
    const numberOfResults = options.length;
    return (
        <div className='panel panel-default'>
            <div className='panel-heading'>
                <h4><strong>Basic Query</strong></h4>
                <p>{numberOfResults} Results Found</p>
            </div>

            <div className='panel-body'>
                <input 
                    className='form-control' 
                    placeholder='Enter Keyword or Position Code' 
                    value={this.state.term}
                    onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
                />
                <hr />
                <h4>Position:</h4>
                <select className='form-control'>
                    <option></option>
                    {options}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The infinite loop is because you call setState in render renderOptionsSelect method, which is called in render method.

You can't call setState in render method, it should raise a warning.

To solve your problem, you might calculate the number of item on the onInputChange method.